# How do you use Match/Regular Expression with a variable in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

This works:

```
match = string.match(/\A>.*\(12345\)/)
puts match
```

How do I do the same thing with a variable? Something like this:

```
number = 12345
match = string.match("/\A>.*\(#{number}\)/")
puts match
```

Comment: Are you getting an error? Because as far as I can tell that should probably work.

Comment: Remove the quotes from your second example.

Comment: The slash markers `/.../` are to delimit the regular expression, they're not actually part of it. `%r{...}` is one of the alternate ways of expressing one, so the slashes aren't magical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regex literal already accepts interpolation. Just do

```
match = string.match(/\A>.*\(#{number}\)/)
```

Comment: Might want `Regexp.escape(number)` just to be safe. Someone might put in `123.456` which could match all kinds of junk.